# Is it possible to fix an old commit in git?

Tags: git, version-control

I've currently noticed that there were a couple of minor details that were left out from an older commit X (let's say, HEAD~10) in my current branch. I'd like to know if it's still possible to to commit my changes to that old git commit.

I'm only working locally, so no weird remote restrictions apply.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that if you don't push elsewhere and preferably if you have linear history. You just commit you minor things and use `git rebase --interactive`, then you can either reorder and squash or edit your commits.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout that commit

Make the changes and commit with --amend to modify it

Rebate the missing commits back onto head and you should be where you are now with the amends in place

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new commit adding the desired changes with the subject "fixup! [commit message of HEAD~10]" and run `git rebase --interactive --autosquash`